# TeXcolorrgb vs. setrgbcolor

Tags: color, pstricks, postscript

I wonder if there is a tiny difference of the produced color within the resulting pdf.

Within this given example - two colored lines differently setup.

One line is setup with LaTeX, the other line is setup with PSTricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red!30}{\rule{4cm}{5mm}}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4,1)
\psline[linecolor=red!30,linewidth=0.5cm](0,0)(4,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it via `dvips` and then regarding the resulting `*.ps` file, I get the following lines within the `*.ps` file:

For the LaTeX generated line, I see: `1 0.7 0.7 TeXcolorrgb`

For the PSTricks generated line, I see: `1 0.7 0.7  setrgbcolor`

Will both produce the exact same colors within the resulting PDF and how can I proof the color within the final PDF?

Any hints welcome.

Kind regards,

Jürgen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setrgbcolor` is the PostScript primitive to set an RGB colour. `TeXcolorrgb` is the name dvips inserts into the PostScript stream if you use a color `\special` with model `rgb`, this indirection allows for user specified models, but in the case of `rgb` the header file `color.pro` just defines `TeXcolorrgb` to be `setrgbcolor`

```
/TeXcolorrgb { setrgbcolor } def
```

so the two forms are the same thing.

Comment: ... any hint still for how to proof that within the final PDF?

Comment: you can set `\pdfcompresslevel=0` then just look for the equivalent pdf  `1 .07 0.7 rg` @JürgenG